# Take a text inside the button to put into a string variable

Tags: javascript, html

So, I have this 4 buttons. Whenever I click one of those buttons, a list of ingredients will appear, each in their own buttons. So, what I'm trying to do is once I click one of those ingredient buttons, the text would be put into a variable. For example, if I click the button with the text, "Beef", written on it, I could save the text as a string on a variable, for example buttonText = "Beef". Try to console.log the text, so I can see that's it's being logged everytime I click it.

```js
let meatIngrList = {
  ingr1: {
    name: "Beef",
    amount: 1,
    amountType: "kg",
    cal: 500,
  },
  ingr2: {
    name: "Pork",
    amount: 1,
    amountType: "kg",
    cal: 400,
  },
  ingr3: {
    name: "Chicken",
    amount: 1,
    amountType: "kg",
    cal: 300,
  },
  ingr4: {
    name: "Fish",
    amount: 1,
    amountType: "kg",
    cal: 200,
  },
};

let vegetableIngrList = {
  ingr1: {
    name: "Carrot",
    amount: 1,
    amountType: "kg",
    cal: 500,
  },
  ingr2: {
    name: "Lettuce",
    amount: 1,
    amountType: "kg",
    cal: 400,
  },
  ingr3: {
    name: "Potato",
    amount: 1,
    amountType: "kg",
    cal: 300,
  },
  ingr4: {
    name: "Eggplant",
    amount: 1,
    amountType: "kg",
    cal: 200,
  },
};

let fruitIngrList = {
  ingr1: {
    name: "Banana",
    amount: 1,
    amountType: "kg",
    cal: 500,
  },
  ingr2: {
    name: "Mango",
    amount: 1,
    amountType: "kg",
    cal: 400,
  },
  ingr3: {
    name: "Apple",
    amount: 1,
    amountType: "kg",
    cal: 300,
  },
  ingr4: {
    name: "Orange",
    amount: 1,
    amountType: "kg",
    cal: 200,
  },
};

let otherIngrList = {
  ingr1: {
    name: "Egg",
    amount: 1,
    amountType: "kg",
    cal: 500,
  },
  ingr2: {
    name: "Peanut",
    amount: 1,
    amountType: "kg",
    cal: 400,
  },
  ingr3: {
    name: "Mayonnaise",
    amount: 1,
    amountType: "kg",
    cal: 300,
  },
  ingr4: {
    name: "Chocolate",
    amount: 1,
    amountType: "kg",
    cal: 200,
  },
};

// Change list of Ingredient Buttons based on Tab
editIngrList = document.getElementById("edit-ingr-list");
meatIngrTab = document.getElementById("edit-ingr-tab-meat");
vegetableIngrTab = document.getElementById("edit-ingr-tab-vegetable");
fruitIngrTab = document.getElementById("edit-ingr-tab-fruit");
otherIngrTab = document.getElementById("edit-ingr-tab-other");

meatIngrTab.addEventListener("click", function () {
  deleteIngrList();
  createIngrList(meatIngrList);
});
vegetableIngrTab.addEventListener("click", function () {
  deleteIngrList();
  createIngrList(vegetableIngrList);
});
fruitIngrTab.addEventListener("click", function () {
  deleteIngrList();
  createIngrList(fruitIngrList);
});
otherIngrTab.addEventListener("click", function () {
  deleteIngrList();
  createIngrList(otherIngrList);
});

//functions
function deleteIngrList() {
  const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("edit-ingr-item");
  while (elements.length > 0) {
    elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
  }
  return elements;
}

function createIngrList(ingrList) {
  for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(ingrList).length; i++) {
    let ingrListBtn = document.createElement("button");
    ingrListBtnText = ingrList[Object.keys(ingrList)[i]].name;
    ingrListBtn.innerHTML = ingrListBtnText;
    editIngrList.appendChild(ingrListBtn);
    ingrListBtn.classList.add("edit-ingr-item");
  }
  return ingrList;
}
```

```html
<button id="edit-ingr-tab-meat">Meat</button>
<button id="edit-ingr-tab-vegetable">Vegetables</button>
<button id="edit-ingr-tab-fruit">Fruits</button>
<button id="edit-ingr-tab-other">Others</button>

<br/>
<div id="edit-ingr-list"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `onclick` function for the button, in the for loop itself.

```js
let meatIngrList = {
  ingr1: {
    name: "Beef",
    amount: 1,
    amountType: "kg",
    cal: 500,
  },
  ingr2: {
    name: "Pork",
    amount: 1,
    amountType: "kg",
    cal: 400,
  },
  ingr3: {
    name: "Chicken",
    amount: 1,
    amountType: "kg",
    cal: 300,
  },
  ingr4: {
    name: "Fish",
    amount: 1,
    amountType: "kg",
    cal: 200,
  },
};

let vegetableIngrList = {
  ingr1: {
    name: "Carrot",
    amount: 1,
    amountType: "kg",
    cal: 500,
  },
  ingr2: {
    name: "Lettuce",
    amount: 1,
    amountType: "kg",
    cal: 400,
  },
  ingr3: {
    name: "Potato",
    amount: 1,
    amountType: "kg",
    cal: 300,
  },
  ingr4: {
    name: "Eggplant",
    amount: 1,
    amountType: "kg",
    cal: 200,
  },
};

let fruitIngrList = {
  ingr1: {
    name: "Banana",
    amount: 1,
    amountType: "kg",
    cal: 500,
  },
  ingr2: {
    name: "Mango",
    amount: 1,
    amountType: "kg",
    cal: 400,
  },
  ingr3: {
    name: "Apple",
    amount: 1,
    amountType: "kg",
    cal: 300,
  },
  ingr4: {
    name: "Orange",
    amount: 1,
    amountType: "kg",
    cal: 200,
  },
};

let otherIngrList = {
  ingr1: {
    name: "Egg",
    amount: 1,
    amountType: "kg",
    cal: 500,
  },
  ingr2: {
    name: "Peanut",
    amount: 1,
    amountType: "kg",
    cal: 400,
  },
  ingr3: {
    name: "Mayonnaise",
    amount: 1,
    amountType: "kg",
    cal: 300,
  },
  ingr4: {
    name: "Chocolate",
    amount: 1,
    amountType: "kg",
    cal: 200,
  },
};

// Change list of Ingredient Buttons based on Tab
editIngrList = document.getElementById("edit-ingr-list");
meatIngrTab = document.getElementById("edit-ingr-tab-meat");
vegetableIngrTab = document.getElementById("edit-ingr-tab-vegetable");
fruitIngrTab = document.getElementById("edit-ingr-tab-fruit");
otherIngrTab = document.getElementById("edit-ingr-tab-other");
let buttonText;

meatIngrTab.addEventListener("click", function() {
  deleteIngrList();
  createIngrList(meatIngrList);
});
vegetableIngrTab.addEventListener("click", function() {
  deleteIngrList();
  createIngrList(vegetableIngrList);
});
fruitIngrTab.addEventListener("click", function() {
  deleteIngrList();
  createIngrList(fruitIngrList);
});
otherIngrTab.addEventListener("click", function() {
  deleteIngrList();
  createIngrList(otherIngrList);
});

//functions
function deleteIngrList() {
  const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("edit-ingr-item");
  while (elements.length > 0) {
    elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
  }
  return elements;
}

function createIngrList(ingrList) {
  for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(ingrList).length; i++) {
    let ingrListBtn = document.createElement("button");
    ingrListBtnText = ingrList[Object.keys(ingrList)[i]].name;
    ingrListBtn.innerHTML = ingrListBtnText;
    editIngrList.appendChild(ingrListBtn);
    ingrListBtn.classList.add("edit-ingr-item");

    ingrListBtn.onclick = function() {
      buttonText = ingrListBtn.innerHTML;
      console.log(buttonText)
    }
  }
  return ingrList;
}
```

```html
<button id="edit-ingr-tab-meat">Meat</button>
<button id="edit-ingr-tab-vegetable">Vegetables</button>
<button id="edit-ingr-tab-fruit">Fruits</button>
<button id="edit-ingr-tab-other">Others</button>

<br/>
<div id="edit-ingr-list"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let buttonText;
document.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    if (event.target.tagName === "BUTTON") {
        buttonText = event.target.innerHTML;
        console.log(buttonText);
    }
})
```

Does this cover your use-case?

Answer (score 1):

[Event Delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) is a good idea to add document wide click handlers for anything (including not yet existing elements). I have simplified your code a bit and rewritten the event handling to event delegation. To identify the ingredients list clicked, a [`data-attribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) is used.

```js
const ingrLists = getLists();
document.addEventListener("click", handle);

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.id.startsWith("edit-ingr-tab")) {
    document.querySelectorAll("[data-ingr]")
      .forEach( bttn => bttn.classList.remove("selected"));
    evt.target.classList.add("selected");
    const forList = evt.target.dataset.ingr;
    return createIngrList(ingrLists[forList], forList);
  }
  
  if (evt.target.classList.contains("edit-ingr-item")) {
    console.clear();
    // for the example logging the ingredient object values from the clicked value.
    // Here you can do something with the clicked button value
    // (e.g. assign it to a variable)
    const listItem = Object.values(ingrLists[evt.target.dataset.ingredientlist])
      .find(v => v.name === evt.target.textContent);
    console.log(`clicked: ${listItem.name} (amount: ${listItem.amount}${
      listItem.amountType}, cal: ${listItem.cal})`);
  }
}

function createIngrList(ingrList, forList) {
  const editIngrList = document.querySelector("#edit-ingr-list");
  editIngrList.textContent = "";
  Object.keys(ingrList).forEach(key =>
    editIngrList.insertAdjacentHTML(
      "beforeend",
      `<button class="edit-ingr-item" data-ingredientlist="${forList}">${
        ingrList[key].name}</button>`)
  );
}

function getLists() {
  let meatIngrList = {
    ingr1: {
      name: "Beef",
      amount: 1,
      amountType: "kg",
      cal: 500,
    },
    ingr2: {
      name: "Pork",
      amount: 1,
      amountType: "kg",
      cal: 400,
    },
    ingr3: {
      name: "Chicken",
      amount: 1,
      amountType: "kg",
      cal: 300,
    },
    ingr4: {
      name: "Fish",
      amount: 1,
      amountType: "kg",
      cal: 200,
    },
  };

  let vegetableIngrList = {
    ingr1: {
      name: "Carrot",
      amount: 1,
      amountType: "kg",
      cal: 500,
    },
    ingr2: {
      name: "Lettuce",
      amount: 1,
      amountType: "kg",
      cal: 400,
    },
    ingr3: {
      name: "Potato",
      amount: 1,
      amountType: "kg",
      cal: 300,
    },
    ingr4: {
      name: "Eggplant",
      amount: 1,
      amountType: "kg",
      cal: 200,
    },
  };

  let fruitIngrList = {
    ingr1: {
      name: "Banana",
      amount: 1,
      amountType: "kg",
      cal: 500,
    },
    ingr2: {
      name: "Mango",
      amount: 1,
      amountType: "kg",
      cal: 400,
    },
    ingr3: {
      name: "Apple",
      amount: 1,
      amountType: "kg",
      cal: 300,
    },
    ingr4: {
      name: "Orange",
      amount: 1,
      amountType: "kg",
      cal: 200,
    },
  };

  let otherIngrList = {
    ingr1: {
      name: "Egg",
      amount: 1,
      amountType: "kg",
      cal: 500,
    },
    ingr2: {
      name: "Peanut",
      amount: 1,
      amountType: "kg",
      cal: 400,
    },
    ingr3: {
      name: "Mayonnaise",
      amount: 1,
      amountType: "kg",
      cal: 300,
    },
    ingr4: {
      name: "Chocolate",
      amount: 1,
      amountType: "kg",
      cal: 200,
    },
  };

  return {
    meat: meatIngrList,
    vegetables: vegetableIngrList,
    fruit: fruitIngrList,
    other: otherIngrList
  };
}
```

```css
button {
  margin: 0 5px;
}

button.selected {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<button id="edit-ingr-tab-meat" data-ingr="meat">Meat</button>
<button id="edit-ingr-tab-vegetable" data-ingr="vegetables">Vegetables</button>
<button id="edit-ingr-tab-fruit" data-ingr="fruit">Fruits</button>
<button id="edit-ingr-tab-other" data-ingr="other">Others</button>

<p id="edit-ingr-list"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were to modify the source data by unifying into a single object you might find that you can then simplify the entire piece of code by removing individual functions and using a single event handler. When new items are created if you use `dataset` attributes you can assign arbitrary data to each new button which is easily processed in subsequent button clicks.

```js
let data={
  meat: {
    ingr1: {
      name: "Beef",
      amount: 1,
      amountType: "kg",
      cal: 500
    },
    ingr2: {
      name: "Pork",
      amount: 1,
      amountType: "kg",
      cal: 400
    },
    ingr3: {
      name: "Chicken",
      amount: 1,
      amountType: "kg",
      cal: 300
    },
    ingr4: {
      name: "Fish",
      amount: 1,
      amountType: "kg",
      cal: 200
    },
  },
  vegetable: {
    ingr1: {
      name: "Carrot",
      amount: 1,
      amountType: "kg",
      cal: 500
    },
    ingr2: {
      name: "Lettuce",
      amount: 1,
      amountType: "kg",
      cal: 400
    },
    ingr3: {
      name: "Potato",
      amount: 1,
      amountType: "kg",
      cal: 300
    },
    ingr4: {
      name: "Eggplant",
      amount: 1,
      amountType: "kg",
      cal: 200
    }
  },
  fruit: {
    ingr1: {
      name: "Banana",
      amount: 1,
      amountType: "kg",
      cal: 500
    },
    ingr2: {
      name: "Mango",
      amount: 1,
      amountType: "kg",
      cal: 400
    },
    ingr3: {
      name: "Apple",
      amount: 1,
      amountType: "kg",
      cal: 300
    },
    ingr4: {
      name: "Orange",
      amount: 1,
      amountType: "kg",
      cal: 200
    },
  },
  other: {
    ingr1: {
      name: "Egg",
      amount: 1,
      amountType: "kg",
      cal: 500
    },
    ingr2: {
      name: "Peanut",
      amount: 1,
      amountType: "kg",
      cal: 400
    },
    ingr3: {
      name: "Mayonnaise",
      amount: 1,
      amountType: "kg",
      cal: 300
    },
    ingr4: {
      name: "Chocolate",
      amount: 1,
      amountType: "kg",
      cal: 200
    }
  }
};

const div=document.getElementById('edit-ingr-list');


document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach( bttn=>{
  bttn.addEventListener('click',function(e){

    div.querySelectorAll('.edit-ingr-item').forEach( n=>div.removeChild(n) );

    // create ingredients list
    let ul=document.createElement('ul');
      ul.className='ingredients';

    // find the correct category based upon last item in ID when split using '-'
    let cat=this.id.split('-').pop();
    
    // process the source data for discovered category
    Object.keys( data[cat] ).forEach( key=>{
      let obj=data[cat][key];
      let b=document.createElement('button');
        
        // set the text & class of the new button
        b.innerText=obj.name;
        b.className='edit-ingr-item';

        // add all properties from food ingredient object to the button as dataset attributes
        Object.keys( obj ).forEach( k => b.dataset[k]=obj[k] )

        // Click event handler for new buttons
        b.addEventListener('click',function(e){
          // clear the UL of children
          ul.innerHTML='';

          // Show the parent food category in console
          console.clear();
          console.log(cat)


          // process all the previously assigned dataset attributes.
          // These attributes are governed wholly by the original source data variable.
          Object.keys( this.dataset ).forEach( k=>{

            // show the various dataset attributes & associated values.
            console.log( k, this.dataset[k] );

            //display ingredients & data in the HTML `UL` element
            let li=document.createElement('li');
              li.innerText=[k,this.dataset[k]].join(':')

            ul.append( li )
          });
        });



      // delete previous ingredients - if any
      let list=div.querySelector('ul.ingredients');
      if( list )div.removeChild( list );

      div.append( b );
      div.append( ul );
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<button id='edit-ingr-tab-meat'>Meat</button>
<button id='edit-ingr-tab-vegetable'>Vegetables</button>
<button id='edit-ingr-tab-fruit'>Fruits</button>
<button id='edit-ingr-tab-other'>Others</button>

<br />
<div id='edit-ingr-list'></div>
```